# Login to SQL Server database not working

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a log in page in C# web page. I have written that code which I think is correct. The user supposed to key in the correct username and password. Before I go any further into modifying after success log in I temporarily set the label 1 to show me whether it's correct or not. However it doesn't work and every time I tried to key in the correct data, it always show "failed".

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SeminarDB; Integrated security=true;");

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string str = "select * from Member where Username='" + signintext.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordtext.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            string login = signintext.Text;
            string pwd = passwordtext.Text;

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                if ((dr["Username"].ToString() == login) && (dr["Password"].ToString() == pwd))
                {
                    Label1.Text = "success!";
                    visibl = true;
                }
                else
                {
                     Label1.Text = "failed!";
                }
            }

            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Comment: You have opted for "integrated security" according to your connection string. Why do you have to enter a user / password, then? What is your security model on the DB side?

Comment: Provide the exact error message..

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection! And please also: ***do NOT*** ever store passwords ***in clear text*** into your database tables!!

Comment: there is no error message. Its just show "failed" as if i entered the wrong data even though i entered the correct ones.

Comment: Label1 showing failed? try to run the same query in sql server new query..

Comment: yes it is. The label 1 is showing failed message.

Comment: Are you sure this routine is actually being called? Label 1 must be showing failed! **before** you call this routine, since if you enter the wrong information, then dr.Read() should not return any rows and hence if won't enter the while loop and those won't set the label to failed!.

Comment: run it in debugger and have a look what's going on, step by step. and i strongly agree with @marc_s , use parameters. makes your life so much easier.

Comment: Put a debugger on      **if ((dr["Username"].ToString()**... control line, see what's inside dr, login, and pwd.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it works

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SeminarDB; Integrated security=true;");

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            string str = "select * from Member where Username='" + signintext.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordtext.Text + "'";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {

                 Label1.Text = "success!";
                 visibl = true;
            }
            else
            {
                 Label1.Text = "failed!";
            }    

            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Label1.Text = ex.Message;
        }
}
```

Comment: Care to **explain** what you've done / changed compared to the OP's code?? What have you tried to fix? **Don't** just dump a pile of code on us!!

Comment: it did work actually.I changed my codes if that and I can now see the "success" with the correct data keyed in. i really appreciate your help.

Comment: The difference is this one doesn't bother to recheck the returned values it just let's the SQL handle to comparison. The likelyhood is that due to the collation on the server the SQL query is case insensitive whereas  the c# comparison is not, you are getting different results.

Comment: I would mark this answer up but it is also vulnerable to SQL injection. Please update the answer to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method..

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=SeminarDB; Integrated security=true;");

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        string str = "select count(*) from Member where Username='" + signintext.Text + "' and Password='" + passwordtext.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        string login = signintext.Text;
        string pwd = passwordtext.Text;

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            if ((dr[0] > 0)
            {
                Label1.Text = "success!"; 
            }
            else
            {
                 Label1.Text = "failed!";
            }
        }

        dr.Close();
        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Label1.Text = ex.Message;
    }
```

}